# How to find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} ( 4x/\sin 2x + x\cos2x )$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Compute

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[-\dfrac{4x}{\sin 2x} + \dfrac{x}{\cos 2x}\right]$$

Obviously I can't plug in 0. I noticed the sin and cos are both 2x. Is there a way to combine them into tan? I don't want to do illegal math, lol.

Comment: If I am reading your expression correctly, the second part has limit $0$ so we can forget about it.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: If the limit of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both exist, then $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)+\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$. And it is clear that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\cos 2x}=0$, since the top approaches $0$ and the bottom approaches $1$.  So we need only find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-4x}{\sin x}$. I will leave this to you, or to someone who writes an answer.

Comment: -2. Thanks!‏‏‏‏

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, the limit is indeed $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

It was already explained [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911679/calculus-limits/911772#comment1881515_911679) that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[-\dfrac{4x}{\sin 2x} + \dfrac{x}{\cos 2x}\right] = -\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{4x}{\sin 2x}$$
since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\cos 2x}=0$.

To compute $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{4x}{\sin 2x}$ le us substitute $t=2x$. We get
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{4x}{\sin 2x} = 2\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{t}{\sin t}.$$

So we obtained a well-known limit for which there are various approaches: [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

It is also useful to notice that the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}.$ is precisely the derivative of $\sin x$ at 0, since by definition of derivative we have
$$(\sin x)'|_{x=0} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x-0} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$